# .bind() not working to set cookie

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, translation

I have a function to set cookies, and i have .bind() set on some of my links so that they trigger the cookie function when clicked. Right now, when they are clicked no cookie is set. I've spent hours on this and cant figure it out.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function createCookie(name,value,days) { 
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = ";
 expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}
else {
    var expires = "";
}
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
$("a#en").bind("click", function () {
    createCookie('TR_LNG', 'en', 90);
});
$("a#fr").bind("click", function () {
    createCookie('TR_LNG', 'fr', 90);
});
$("a#de").bind("click", function () {
    createCookie('TR_LNG', 'de', 90);
});
$("a#ja").bind("click", function () {
    createCookie('TR_LNG', 'ja', 90);
});
$("a#pl").bind("click", function () {
    createCookie('TR_LNG', 'pl', 90);
});
$("a#es").bind("click", function () {
    createCookie('TR_LNG', 'es', 90);
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="langselectsplash" class="langselectsplash">
    <div id="select">
        <img src="http://mysite.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/sarvalogo2.png"
        />
        <p>
            <style>
            #tr_setdeflang {
                display:none;
            }

            </style>
            <div class="no_translate transposh_flags">
                <a id="en" href="/about/" class="tr_active">English</a>
                <a id="fr" href="/fr/about/">Français</a>
                <a id="de" href="/de/about/">Deutsch</a>
                <a id="ja" href="/ja/about/">日本語</a>
                <a id="pl" href="/pl/about/">Polski</a>
                <a id="es" href="/es/about/">Español</a>
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="langsplashfade"></div>
```

**The PHP code that outputs the above:**

```
<?php
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function createCookie(name,value,days) { \nif (days) { \nvar date = new Date();\n date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));\n var expires = \";\n expires=\"+date.toGMTString();\n} else { \nvar expires = \"\";}document.cookie = name+\"=\"+value+expires+\"; path=/\";}\n";
foreach ($args as $langrecord) {
    echo "$(\"a#{$langrecord['isocode']}\").bind(\"click\", function() {createCookie('TR_LNG','{$langrecord['isocode']}',90);});\n";
}
echo "</script>";
?>
   <?php
echo " <div id=\"langselectsplash\" class=\"langselectsplash\"><div id=\"select\"><img src=\"http://mysite.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/sarvalogo2.png\" /><p>";
?>
           <?php
echo "<style>#tr_setdeflang{display:none;}</style><div class=\"" . NO_TRANSLATE_CLASS . " transposh_flags\" >";
foreach ($args as $langrecord) {
    echo "<a id=\"{$langrecord['isocode']}\" href=\"{$langrecord['url']}\"" . ($langrecord['active'] ? ' class="tr_active"' : '') . '>' . "{$langrecord['langorig']}</a>";
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the code where you are binding events on the DOM ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Your code
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
//Your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

look at your log:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
var expires = ";
```

You have an error I think you want:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) { 
    var expires = "";
    if (days) { 
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = ";expires=" +date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

because you are opening a string on one line and never closes it at the moment. And the code could be rewritten to:

```
$("#en, #fr, #de, #ja, #pl, #es").bind("click", function() {
    createCookie('TR_LNG', this.id, 90);
});
```

or even better add a css Class on those anchor links and target that instead (for example with your current site: `$(".transposh_flags a")` would do the same as the code above.

Comment: Based on the way the question is phrased I think `var expires = ";` was just a copy error.  Anyway, the problem related to bind appears to be the fact that the event binding needs to occur upon DOM ready.

Comment: @marteljn Because of the error in the js, the cookie won't be set, which is what the question is about. But it also definitely needs to be binded once the DOM is ready, so I actually think both the answers is correct

Comment: taht didn't make any difference. But i have made the change anyways, for the first part of your answer the second part i will try once this is resolved.

Comment: @theatomicdude Also make sure that cookies are enabled in your browser (I believe it will be, but always good to make double sure)

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it did provide some helpful tips, but it needed to be binded, that fixed it.

Comment: @marteljn if you visited his/hers website you had the same error, so it was not just a copy error.